# Android SQLite search exact string

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my SQLite DB Table I have rows with column month. The column might contain one month only, but also multiple months separated by asterisk.

```
E.g.
1st row MONTH: 1*
2nd:  3*4*9*
3rd:  12*
4th:  2*5*
```

I am trying to get all rows, where e.g. the month column contains 2*, it means February.

```
Assume that month = 2 //february
month = month + "*"; 
String Query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + month LIKE '%"+month+"%'";
```

I thought this will work fine, but... as in 3rd row I have 12* and this should be December, the query returns this row when it looks for february, as it finds 2* in 12*.

Is there a way to look for the exact string? So when I search 2*, it will find only 2* alone, not in 12*. The same issue with November for 11* that will find also January search.

One maybe bad, but working idea I have is to write month in DB like: (2)(5)(12)

Then it will find exactly only (2) when searching (2) and will not return (12).

Answer (score 2):

Not that it is recommended to store lists in a column the following could be used (assuming the column's name is month):-

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE '*'||month LIKE '%*'||'" + month + "'||'%'";
```

This prefixes the value extracted with an `*` so all numbers will be enclosed with `*`'s. The argument e.g. `2*` is then made to be `*2*` and thus not like `12*....` or `....*12*....`

To demonstrate the above, when resolved, consider the following:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo (month TEXT);
INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('1*'),('3*4*9*'),('12*'),('2*5*'),('1*2*3*4*5*6*7*'),('8*9*10*11*12*'),('7*6*5*4*3*2*1*');
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE '*'||month LIKE '%*'||'12*'||'%';
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE '*'||month LIKE '%*'||'2*'||'%';
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE '*'/*<<<<< prefix value extracted from db with an * (asterisk) */||month/*<<<<< the month column*/ LIKE '%*'||/* >>>>>*/'1*'/*<<<<< the search argument  */||'%';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo; /* Cleanup demo */
```

- the 3rd SELECT attempts to explain some parts of demo query via comments

Resulting in:-

[image]

- both rows that contain 12 have been extracted

and

[image]

- ONLY rows that have 2 have been extracted, rows with 12 have not been extracted.

and

[image]

this one demonstrates the same BUT also the argument being first and last value.

Comment: Seems a good solution, thank you for going into details as well

Answer (score -1):

As you already found, that way of storing months is not optimal for searches.

When I store data like that, I prefer to use a 12-character string of 0's and 1's, each position representing a month.

So your example would be something like this:

```
1st row: 100000000000
2nd row: 001100001000
3rd row: 000000000001
4th row: 010010000000
```

Then, to search for a specific month, you just need to check the corresponding position:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, POSITION, 1) = '1'
```

Comment: I've got your logic, but for me it would be a pain to add 12 digits for 1000 lines of items in DB and make no mistake with positions of the months

Comment: Oh, sorry. When you explained at the end of your question that you had the possibility of storing the months with parenthesis instead of asterisks, I thought you were open to other storing alternatives.

Comment: well yes, but is easier for me to add 3 months in a column as 12 digits with caring about the position of 1 for each of 1000 plants in my DB (I have all data in Excel and automatically converted and inserted to DB). Btw. it wasn't me that downvoted you :)